# Add business objects to contacts

Tags: abap

I've successfully created a contact in the SAP IS-U (Release 618) system using the function: `BCONTACT_CREATE`

> EDIT:
> Since this question was voted "close" for being "too broad" - here's some very specific code:

```
  DATA:
      ls_contact            TYPE bpc01_bcontact_auto,
      ls_contact_properties TYPE bcont,
      lv_contact_text       TYPE string,
      lv_bp                 TYPE bu_partner,
      lv_bpcontact_id       TYPE ct_contact,
      lv_no_dialog          TYPE flag VALUE abap_true,
      lv_repid              TYPE syst-repid.

*    Main logic
    lv_contact_text = 'Test'.
    lv_bp           = '0010000062'.

    ls_contact_properties-cclass = '0003'.
    ls_contact_properties-activity = '0001'.
    ls_contact_properties-f_coming = '3'.


*  Mapping
*--------------------------------------------------------------------*
    ls_contact-notice-line    = lv_contact_text.
    ls_contact-bcontd         = ls_contact_properties.

* set flag to use auto data
    ls_contact-bcontd_use     = abap_true.
    lv_repid                  = sy-repid.

    CALL FUNCTION 'BCONTACT_CREATE'
      EXPORTING
        x_no_dialog     = lv_no_dialog
        x_auto          = ls_contact
        x_prgcontext    = lv_repid
        x_partner       = lv_bp
      IMPORTING
        y_new_bpcontact = lv_bpcontact_id
      EXCEPTIONS
        existing        = 1
        foreign_lock    = 2
        number_error    = 3
        general_fault   = 4
        input_error     = 5
        not_authorized  = 6
        OTHERS          = 7.
```

When I open the created contact in the `BCT2` transaction I see the nothing under Business-Objects:

[image: Default Contact - No Business-Objects]

How can I programmatically add a business object to a contact, so that it is displayed here like this?

[image: Contact with Business-Objects]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it a solution!

First create variables (a table and a structure for filling the table) for your business objects that you want to add (I saw some code that had a limit of 5 so I just set that too to be safe):

```
lt_business_objs      TYPE TABLE OF bpc_obj INITIAL SIZE 5,
ls_business_obj       TYPE bpc_obj,
```

Next append your object, in this example I'm just appending one:

```
* Append business objects
*--------------------------------------------------------------------*
ls_business_obj-objkey  = 'The value here may be your business object input value'.
ls_business_obj-objrole = 'DEFAULT'. "Don't know what this is for...
ls_business_obj-objtype = 'OBJECT_NAME'. "Name of your business object - seen in table TOJTB
APPEND ls_business_obj TO lt_business_objs.
```

And lastly put the object list into the contact structure:

```
ls_contact-iobjects       = lt_business_objs.
```